# where should i place bluecove-2.1.0 folder

Tags: java, eclipse, bluetooth, bluecove

I am trying to write a project that communicates with a Bluetooth device and receives information from it. I googled it and from what I understood I had to get a package named 'bluecove' which will contain all I need. I downloaded the jar file, and (in Eclipse) by right-clicking on 'my project>build path>jar file>bluecove', I added the jar file into my project. When I try to run some lines of code, it gives me an error that says that some content is unavailable:

```
Native Library intelbth_x64 not available
Native Library bluecove_x64 not available
```

Then I went back to the bluecove website and i saw there another Windows file for download called 'bluecove-2.1.0-sources.tar.gz'

here is a link:
http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/downloads/list

When I downloaded it, there was a folder inside named 'bluecove-2.1.0' which I think I have to copy into one of the system's folders. What should I be doing here?

Thanks
p.s i will need the answer as soon as possible - in the next 9 hours at most, please help me 
and again thanks

Comment: Have you checked [the bluecove wiki](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/wiki/Documentation#Runtime_configuration)?

Comment: Have you tried googling that message? This links turns up pretty fast: http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/issues/detail?id=109

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://code.google.com/p/bluecove/issues/detail?id=109) (commented by oxc), you need to download the .jar specified: http://snapshot.bluecove.org/distribution/download/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT/2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.62/